# HR Module - Setting Permission for viewing Contracts

Tags: customization, odoo

I want to set permission for viewing contracts based on groups

For Example I have organization with 5 User.(A,B,C,D,E)

Here
A is in group 'Division Head'
B is in group 'Manager'
and C,D & E all are in group 'My Employees' .

What I need to is

1. If A is logged into application he can see the contracts of all employees of his division(A to E)
2. If B is logged into application he can see the contracts of the employees who are all reporting to him that is C,D and E.
3. If any of employee logged into application they can See only his / her contract alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this type of permissions in sale contracts.You can see three types of group for sales.
1.Manager
2.User
3.User -see all leads

Provide the first group, manager for the user A, then the third group, see all leads for the user B and second group for the users C,D and E.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [record rules](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/book/8/8_20_Config/8_20_Config_accessRights.html#record-rules-for-objects) are supposed to handle that type of thing, but I haven't used them. You might have to add some [related fields](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type.html#relational-types) or [functional fields](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type.html#functional-fields) if the table doesn't already have enough information to test the relationships you want to test.